# Why does the console in Chrome display 404 not found in browserLink?

Tags: visual-studio, signalr, visual-studio-2013, browser-link

I've been using Visual Studio 2013 for a while and love the browserlink feature. However, from time to time it gives me 404's in the developer console in chrome or ie. (Haven't tried any other browsers):
[image]

Am I doing something wrong? It's not breaking anything, but it's somewhat annoying as I tend to use the console for monitoring SignalR (not the browserlink one..) and other javascript outputs. Red color makes me think something is wrong when all it often is, is the broweserlink "acting up".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug (at least if you're seeing this while using websockets in a cross-domain setup): 
https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2569